# Creating duplicate features - many to one - in qgis

Tags: qgis, duplication

Essentially I have a shapefile of polylines and wish to create duplicates and based on attribute data.

I have route data for individuals as polylines. Then I have attribute data which tells me the number of people and what are the members of the group. The number of individuals is variable ranging  from 1 -10 and I would want to duplicate to create a single line for each individual.

This is to examine footfall. I realise that with a grid I could simply sum the number of members for each polyline togive me footfall. However I wish to examine different members of the group differently and treat their impacts differently, therefore I need single polylines for each member of the group.

A similar question has been asked (below), but this is in ArcGIS and I have only QGIS available.

[Creating duplicate features based on many-to-one conversion of related table?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2037/creating-duplicate-features-based-on-many-to-one-conversion-of-related-table)

Answer (score 2):

A Linear Referencing System may be of use here. This way you do not have to create many duplication's of the same data. Take a read of the answer from @gcarrillo on the [QGIS Linear Referencing Post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/130307/qgis-linear-referencing/130331#130331)

From ESRI on [Why to Use Linear Referencing](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/guide-books/linear-referencing/what-is-linear-referencing.htm#GUID-D94FBBB0-1422-4415-A248-B584672ED5C4):

> Linear referencing is also used to associate multiple sets of attributes to portions of linear features without requiring that underlying lines be segmented (split) each time that attribute values change. For example, most road centerline feature classes are segmented where three or more road segments intersect and where the road names change.
>   Users often want to record many additional attributes about the roads. Without the use of linear referencing, this could require that roads be split into many tiny segments at each location where attribute values change. As an alternative, these situations can be handled as linear referencing events along the roads as in the figure below:

Multiple sets of attributes for road features

[image]