# Multiplying points to another feature table using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, feature-class

I have a point feature class like this:
[image]
And another table looks like this:
[image]
How can I add point's xy coordinate to that table based on their No. and automatic multiply as their No. multiplies using ArcPy?
In the end, it should just looks like this:
[image]

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2037/creating-duplicate-features-based-on-many-to-one-conversion-of-related-table

Comment: I don't think "multiply" means what you think it means.  Perhaps you mean [join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)?

Comment: @KirkKuykendall I tried join and I think join means one to one, but I want one to many.

Comment: Do you want new points feature class, or just update the table with the values?

Comment: @smiller Actually I want a new point feature class, but update the table with the values is also fine, I can generate point later as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like using Python dictionaries. You can house your key and their respective XYs and use the dictionary to update your table.

```
#point feature class
pointFc = r"point\feature\class"

#update table
tab = r"update\table"

import arcpy

#create dictionary
di = {}

#iterate point feature class and store values
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor (pointFc, ["No", "x", "x"]) as curs:
    for no, x, y in curs:
        #store value
        di [no] = (x, y)

#update table
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor (tab, ["No", "x", "y"]) as curs:
    for no, x, y in curs:
        #get value from dictionary
        x, y = di [no]
        row = (no, x, y)
        #update table
        curs.updateRow (row)
```

Comment: That's really helping! Thank you!